# Android: How to check condition with async task return value

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am doing some processing in async task to check some values on server if the value present server php script returns true otherwise false.

everything is working fine, but whenever i am trying to check condition with the http response  string the condition never gets checked..

partial code:

```
CheckDevice cd = new CheckDevice();
String chk[] = new String[1];
    chk[0] = di.imei;
    try {
        cd.execute(chk).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

cd.getFinalResult(); //This returns string "true" (working outside if);


    if(cd.getFinalResult == "true"){
            //This loop never executes... why?
    regButton.setEnabled(false);
        regButton.setText("Device Already Registered");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cd.getFinalResult(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

What is the problem? someone please tell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do,

```
  cd.getFinalResult().equals("true") //OR

  cd.getFinalResult().equalsIgnoreCase("true")
```

as you cannot compare strings using ( == ).

Check [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Compare-Strings-in-Java) for details.

Comment: Nice to hear that. :) You can accept my answer too. :)